# Ajax.net but no script

Tags: asp.net, ajax.net

I want use ajax.net to do some js. like below:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Submit, typeof(Button), "alert", "location.href='test.aspx';", true);

If user turn off the javascript, it will not redirect to another page.

I want to know how to set <noscript></noscript>.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='no-script.aspx'">
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Response.Redirect("test.aspx") which does not require JavaScript and should be supported by most of the modern browsers.